# How to split payments in Stripe without stripe connect?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project that basically allows schools to sort of have their own online school store.
The schools can create their store on our platform and sell their products from there on.

So what I want to do is 'split the payments' between our platforms/project account and the schools account.
For example, when someone buys an item of a specific school, using our platform, I want to split the payment so that after the checkout button is clicked on Stripe, 80% goes to the schools Stripe account and our platform keeps 20%.

BUT I'm stuck on how to implement this.
I saw that one way to do this is use Stripe Connect and I got one person specifying that I can create/use the paymentIntents.create() method twice ( basically creat 1 paymentIntent for the school and the other for our platform, and define some logic in the code to manually split the incoming amount)

SO I don't know which path to follow/is correct.

Should I use Stripe sconnect or create payment intetns twice(obviously they'll have different keys)?

P.S question : IS the the double implementation of paymentIntents a way to split payments without Stripe connect?

Answer (score 1):

From this sentence ‘The schools can create their store on our platform and sell their products from there on’, it sounds like you’re already using [Connect](https://stripe.com/connect). If that is correct, you would NOT need to create two Payment Intents, you can create one Payment Intent and split the payment.

Depending on what [account type](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) these schools are created as, the answer will depend. At a high level, you’d want to start [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and look at the [available charge types](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) for the recommended Connect account type.

If you do not use Connect, then that is correct. You cannot create one Payment Intent and then ‘split’ it like you described. From the limited details, I would recommend that you use Connect as it makes ‘splitting’ funds easier. I also think that the end customer going through your Checkout flow twice would be costly both to you and the customer.